# Regex matching needs to stop at first occurrence of file extension and ignore rest

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to build a regex query that would look for image files and would ignore looking into sub directories.

Check the following strings

```
/content/dam/dev-img-test-folder/huehuehue.gif/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png

/content/dam/someotherdirectory/nonoono.gif/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png


/content/dam/dev-img-test-folder/huehuehue.jpg
/content/dam/some-directory/nononoono.jpg
```

The regex should detect only the last two strings. I tried with /content/dam.*.(jpg|JPG|png), but that gets all four of them.

Can someone guide me to right directions here? Thank you.

Comment: All four are image URLs, so why do you only want the final two.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, edited the sample for a better example. The use case is about triggering a workflow when it finds image in a specific directory, but not in the sub directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/content/dam/[^/]*/[^/]*(jpg|JPG|png)$` will match all files ending (due to $) with `jpg|JPG|png` in any subdir of dam.

If you are looking for variable number of subdirs it would be a different regex.

`.*\.(jpg|JPG|png)$` should match any line ending with `jpg|JPG|png`.

`/([^/]*/){2,5}[^/]*(jpg|JPG|png)$`  will match any file 2 to 5 subdirs deep. You might need to escape parenthesis depending on regex engine/syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When your data has a clear delimiter, such as `/` in this case, you can use `[^...]+` to get everything *except* that character. Which is extremely useful to limit the depth of your search if you use it along with `$`.

In your case, `\/content\/dam\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\.(jpg|JPG|png)$` will work. Also, regex is often case-insensitive. You might not need `JPG` in your string.

https://regex101.com/r/gGvRw3/2/